# Putting an array (at the end OR beginning) subarray of another array

Tags: php, arrays, sub-array

Say I got this array:
`array([0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 1)`, how can I put this as the value of the nth key of another array, making

```
$array = array(
            [0] => array([0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 1)
        )
```

in this example it is the 0th key of array $array

I had browsed with PHP array functions, but I got tired looking for a function that does the same thing

**EDIT.**

Doing: `$array[0] = array(0, 0, 1);`  works great for first loop, but if I would like to add another array as subarray, say `array(1, 1, 1)`, my output should be

```
$array = array(
            [0] => array([0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1)
        )
```

Note that the new array, was added at the end of the last subarray.

Please help! thanks!

**EDIT**

```
$x=0;
while($x<count($WOE_CONTROL)) {
        $j=0;
        while($j<=30) {
            if ($WOE_CONTROL[$x+3]&(1<<$j)) {
                echo '<br />';
                echo '<strong>'.$Castles[$j].'</strong>';
                $castle_data_holder[0] = $WOE_CONTROL[$x];
                $castle_data_holder[1] = $WOE_CONTROL[$x+1];
                $castle_data_holder[2] = $WOE_CONTROL[$x+2];
                $castle_db[$j] = $castle_data_holder;
                unset ($castle_data_holder);
            }
            if ($x+4 < count($WOE_CONTROL)) {echo " ";}
            $j=$j+1;
        }
    $x=$x+4;
}
```

Sorry, there, I am trying to extract all the data in `$WOE_CONTROL` which actually contains binary data, then store them temporarily to `$castle_data_holder` then finally, add it to `$castle_db`

Comment: Why can't you just assign it directly? `$arr[0] = $innerArr;`?

Comment: @JakeKing sorry, I forgot to say that I am doing loop.

Comment: share the whole code with the loop and finalize the question, the people answering in the question are like shooting in the dark trying to hit a target

Comment: if you're just trying to merge, then just use array merge: `$castle_data_holder[0] = array_merge($castle_data_holder[0], $WOE_CONTROL[$x])`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of $array[0] to the array. This produces a multidimensional array.

```
$array[0] = array(0, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this u looking for?

```
$array[] =  array(0,0,1);
$array[] =  array(1,1,1);
$array[] =  array(2,2,2);
// etc...
print_r($array);
```

**EDIT**

```
$array[]['a1'] = array(1,1,1);
$array[]['a2'] = array(2,2,2);
$array[]['a3'] = array(3,3,3);
// etc...
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Sorry, but, that's not what I tried to described, say you have 3 arrays `array(1,1,1);array(2,2,2);array(3,3,3);` I am expecting `$array[] = array(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3);`

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is u need

```
$a = array(1,1,1);
$b = array(2,2,2);
$c = array(3,3,3);
$value = array_merge($a,$b,$c);
print_r($value);
```

**EDIT**

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value)
{
  // I say if $value is an array that u want to  merge
  $arrayToMerge = $value;
  $newArray = array_merge($newArray,$arrayToMerge);
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: `$a,$b,$c` doesn't come together, its a loop. `$a` comes first, then `$b`

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
                if (empty($castle_db[$j])) {
                    $castle_db[$j] = $castle_data_holder;
                }
                else {
                    $castle_db[$j] = array_merge($castle_db[$j],$castle_data_holder);
                }
```

it is going to check if the array is empty if not use merge.

Thanks everyone!